# Regular expression to match exact same block

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Please help me to find out a specific text included block from this file.
I'm reading context using Node js fs.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot /home/site1 
ServerName www.site1.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot /home/site2 
ServerName www.site2.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80> 
DocumentRoot /home/site3 
ServerName www.site3.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

Code:

```
fileContext.toString().split("\n");
 var matched = fileContext.toString().replace( /<VirtualHost[\s\S]*?<\/VirtualHost>/gm,"--matched--" );
```

above code is working fine but it will match all vhost blocks. 
I only needs to find vhost block which is contain "www.site2.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deliberation, I've come to the conclusion that regex isn't going to cut the mustard. I'd recommend using [node-apacheconf](https://github.com/tellnes/node-apacheconf).

```
var name = "www.site2.com";

apacheconf('/etc/apache2/httpd.conf', function(err, config, parser) {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log(config.VirtualHost.filter(function(vh) {
    return vh.ServerName == name;
  }));
});
```

Comment: Yes It is, Cant i define only the site2 as a text

Comment: As a text? You'd have to escape it if you're putting it into regular expression

Comment: Yes im seeking something similar to /<VirtualHost[\s\S]*?(.*)site2(.*)[\s\S]*?<\/VirtualHost>/gm

Comment: One second, I'm trying to fix the regex (It's a little broken). I'll get you an answer soon to your problem.

Comment: @Dhanan Try my updated answer, and let me know if that's working for you. I'm still working on the regex

Comment: That will be the best answer, actually my task is quite complex and this is much helpful. How do i support to improve your reputation